# Difference between jquery ajax post and axios post

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am writing a new application using Vue.js As part of this I need to get an API token from a 3rd party.  The ajax call below is working, and returns the expected response data object, however the axios call fails validation and returns an error message "Username and password cannot be empty".  Any idea what I am doing wrong and why the two calls are being treated differently?

```
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "https://testapi.XXXXXXXX.com/auth",
                data: {
                        username:'TestUser',
                        password: 'TestPwd'
                    },
                success: function(res){
                    console.log("from jquery",res);
                }
            }
        )
    })
    </script>

   <script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el:"#vueapp",
        data:{
            api_key: null
        },
        methods:{
            getNewKey(){
                axios({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url:'https://testapi.XXXXXXXX.com/auth'
                    ,headers:{
                        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                    ,data:{
                        username:'TestUser',
                        password: 'TestPwd'
                    }
                })
                .then(response =>{
                    console.log("From Axios",response);
                })
            }
        },
        created(){
            this.getNewKey();
        }
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: You can check http requests detail in your favourite web browser, using integrated developer tools

Comment: $.ajax form encodes data by default, axios does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the axios documentation:

https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

You need to JSON.stringify your object passed in `data`.

```
data: JSON.stringify({username:'TestUser', password: 'TestPwd'})
```